# Finding number of $4$-digit numbers using $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that at least $2$ digits are identical

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I am supposed to find the number of $4$-digit numbers using digits $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that at least $2$-digits are identical. The answer is given to be $505$. Following is what I have tried.

For sake of convenience let ${5 \choose k}=\text{C}_{k}$. The number of numbers should then be as follows.

$$\text{C}_{3}\frac{4!}{2!}+\text{C}_{2}\frac{4!}{2!2!}+\text{C}_{2}\frac{4!}{3!}+\text{C}_{1}=225$$

What is the mistake? Thanks.

**Edit**:

I get that the answer should be $505=5^4-5!$. But why is the above mentioned method wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For the first term, when you're writing $C_3$ you're only choosing the digits. You're not choosing which digit is repeated. So that term must be multiplied by $3$. Similarly, the third term must be multiplied by $2$ for the digit that will be repeated thrice.

The corrected sum is
$$10×3×12+10×6+10×2×4+5=505$$

Answer (score 1):

You also have to include the number of ways you can select the digits which you have chosen to repeat. For example if you choose $1,2,3$ and are repeating two digits, you can choose to repeat $1,2$ or $1,3$ or $2,3$.